# Implementing Flowchart using AngularJS and Canvas

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html, canvas

I am trying to implement a flowchart using AngularJS and Canvas.
Instead of providing users with a `UI` where they can drag'n'drop UI components, I want to build a command line tool where users will be entering a command to draw a circle, which will convert command to a JSON object and render that object in canvas.

Are there any libraries which I can use to render UI components using JSON Object?

Answer (score 5):

Is canvas a hard requirement or could it be SVG? If so, you could try [AngularJS-FlowChart](https://github.com/codecapers/AngularJS-FlowChart) ([Demo](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16408368/WebUI_FlowChart/index.html) / [Article/Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/709340/Implementing-a-Flowchart-with-SVG-and-AngularJS)) or [angular-jointjs-graph](https://github.com/elsix/angular-jointjs-graph) ([Demo](http://www.jointjs.com/demos)).